# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error: mimeMap

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hello so I'm pretty new to using IIS and Visual Studio but I've managed to launch one website on IIS but when I try to launch this one I get this error across the page:

[image]

Error message:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.mp4'

There's a section that reads **`Config Error:`**so here is my **`web.config`**  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="DetailLogging" value="True"/>
<add key="LoggingConfigFile" value="log4net.config"/>
<add key="DatabaseConnectionString" value="Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=WebEvaluation" />

<add key="Email" value="***********************"/> 
<add key="SupportEmailID" value="*************************"/> 
<add key="ForgotPasswordEmailSubject" value="Butterfly Scheme e-Certification Admin Console - Password Request"/>
<add key="WelcomeMailSubject" value="Butterfly Scheme e-Certification Admin Console"/>
<add key="PasswordChangedMailSubject" value="Butterfly Scheme e-Certification Admin Console - Password Changed"/>
<add key="PasscodeDeleteMailSubject" value="Passcode delete notification - "/>
<add key="Host" value="***********"/>
<add key="PortNo" value="25"/> 
<add key="Password" value="***********"/>
<add key="SiteURL" value="***********************************"/>
<add key="RecordsPerPage" value="20" />
<add key="PasscodeCreateMailSubject" value="Butterfly Scheme e-Certification Passcode List created for : "/>    
<add key ="XlsConnectionString" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1'"/>
<add key ="XlsxConnectionString" value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;'"/>   
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=******************"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=******************"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="2097151" 
executionTimeout="900"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
</system.web> 

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp" mimeType="video/3gpp"/>
</staticContent>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147482624"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 gives "Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type ‘mimeMap’"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725232/visual-studio-2013-gives-cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-of-type-mimemap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add something like this:

```
<remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
```

Or, since the MP4 mime type seems to be already present in the roots configuration file, simply omit the whole line:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
```

If you really want to be sure that the extensions you seem to require are present, this could be a replacement for the `staticContent` tag:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <remove fileExtension=".m4v" />
    <remove fileExtension=".3gp" />

    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp" mimeType="video/3gpp"/>
</staticContent>
```

Comment: When I did this (The `staticContent` tag replacement) I got a [whole new page error.](https://imgur.com/a/hc67X)

Answer (score 0):

Could not load type "PresentationLayer.Global"

Check if you namespace is PresentationLayer or is changed? If changed update it in the markup, by right clicking on Global.asax and select "View Markup"

Comment: It still inherits `PresentationLayer.Global`